# How to organize Interfaces/classes/implementations in the project

Tags: .net, projects-and-solutions, file-organization

I found some questions about how to organise projects (namespace, one class per file etc), but on a more specific note, how do you organize "things" that are very tightly related ?

I usually end up with :

- an **interface** `IMyStuff`
- a **base (sometimes abstract) class** that provides basic skeletton for that interface : `BaseMyStuff`
- **implementation classes** `MyStuffWithBellsAndWhistles`,  `MyStuffWithChocolateFlavours`

It seems to make sense that they should be in the same namespace, but it feels like my folders start to be a bit over-crowded if I put all these files together in the same folder (not actually a real problem, but it feels strange).

**Would it be OK to define both the interface and the base class in the same file ?**

Or **would it be OK to group those things in sub-folders, but in the same namespace** ? like this :

```
-MyNamespace
 |-Interfaces
   | -IMyStuff
   | -IMyOtherStuff
 |-BaseClasses
   | -BaseMyStuff
   | -BaseMyOtherStuff
 |-Implementation
   | -MyStuffWithAwesomeBehaviour
   | -MyStuffWithGreatUsefulness
   | -MyOtherStuffSoNeatYouWillCry
```

**What are the "best practices" regarding this kind of organization ?**

Comment: this is a glimpse of what I use to organize myself: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Rh8.png

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the interfaces is to abstract the implementation and allow for alternative implementations that are not known to the author of the interface, then I would recommend keeping them in an seperate project file. When constructing unit test projects or other consumers of the interface this will allow them to create a project reference that drags in only the interfaces and not the implementations. This means alternative implementations of concrete classes never need to have a reference to the original concreate representation.